# Old code not working with jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code which works fine under jQuery 1.7 or 2.0, but not working under jQuery 1.9. the list become empty when the page is loaded.

The function is used to filter a list, as the user input text, the list will be changed.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" />

<ul>
    <li>fa</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>bcd</li>
    <li>def</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#keyword").keyup(function () {
    $("ul li").hide().filter(":contains('" + ($(this).val()) + "')").show();
}).keyup();
```

For example, when user input "a", the list will be "fa, abc", when user input "bc", the list will be "abc, bcd".

I've created a demo here: [`http://jsfiddle.net/nmVfq/2/`](http://jsfiddle.net/nmVfq/2/)

How can I change this script to make it work under jQuery 1.9?

Comment: Did you include jQuery Migrate plugin ?

Comment: It works for me without any additional plugins

Comment: I don't know why, but removing the quotes around `$(this).val()` fixes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nmVfq/15/

Comment: @billyonecan it could be that `:contents()` sees it as an empty string and searches for empty `li`. Since that will return nothing, `show()` won't work.

Comment: @Spokey that makes sense, it's strange how the behaviour is different between versions though. I wonder if it's documented anywhere

Comment: Its working only for 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#keyword").keyup(function () {
    if($(this).val()==""){
        $("ul li").show();
        return
    }
    $("ul li").hide().filter(":contains('" + ($(this).val()) + "')").show();
}).keyup();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmVfq/17/)

Answer (score 2):

You call keyup() just after you bind the keyup-event. Maybe :contains has changed between versions so an empty parameter is not a match? I did not find any information about that, but I can't look more just now.

Try adding an if statement to check if the value is empty, and show all items if it is.

```
$("#keyword").keyup(function () {
    if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
      $("ul li").show();
    } else {
     $("ul li").hide().filter(":contains('" + ($(this).val()) + "')").show();
    }
}).keyup();
```